# Getting hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister on application startup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am doing some hands on learning of Hibernate JPA. I am trying to run the JPA part from this code -

https://github.com/in28minutes/jpa-with-hibernate/blob/master/01-from-jdbc-to-jpa/Step15.md

Following is all the code and configs -

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

pom.xml - I am using Spring 2.1.11.RELEASE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.in28minutes.database</groupId>
    <artifactId>database-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>database-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

JpaDemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.sandeepan.demo;

import java.util.Date;

import com.example.sandeepan.jpa.PersonJpaRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.sandeepan"})
public class JpaDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    PersonJpaRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        logger.info("User id 10001 -> {}", repository.findById(10001));

        /*
        logger.info("All users -> {}", repository.findAll());
        logger.info("Deleting 10002 -> No of Rows Deleted - {}",
                repository.deleteById(10002));

        logger.info("Inserting 10004 -> {}",
                repository.insert(new Person(10004, "Tara", "Berlin", new Date())));

        logger.info("Update 10003 -> {}",
                repository.update(new Person(10003, "Pieter", "Utrecht", new Date())));
        */
    }
}
```

PersonJpaRepository.java -  Used org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional instead.

```
package com.example.sandeepan.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.sandeepan.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonJpaRepository {

    //connect to the database
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Person findById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);//JPA
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
package com.example.sandeepan.entity;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String location;
    private Date birthDate;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(int id, String name, String location, Date birthDate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public Person(String name, String location, Date birthDate) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\nPerson [id=%s, name=%s, location=%s, birthDate=%s]", id, name, location, birthDate);
    }



}
```

Exact error stacktrace -

```
2019-12-21 22:17:41.939  INFO 24739 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-12-21 22:17:41.943  INFO 24739 --- [           main] c.e.sandeepan.demo.JpaDemoApplication    : Started JpaDemoApplication in 3.822 seconds (JVM running for 4.244)
2019-12-21 22:17:42.042  INFO 24739 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-21 22:17:42.050 ERROR 24739 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:765) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at com.example.sandeepan.demo.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.sandeepan.entity.Person; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.sandeepan.entity.Person
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256) ~[spring-orm-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$$Lambda$463/921640293.proceedWithInvocation(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at com.example.sandeepan.jpa.PersonJpaRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7da9173a.findById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.sandeepan.demo.JpaDemoApplication.run(JpaDemoApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.sandeepan.entity.Person
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3531) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3474) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310) ~[spring-orm-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.sandeepan.jpa.PersonJpaRepository.findById(PersonJpaRepository.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.sandeepan.jpa.PersonJpaRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a023c4d7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.12.RELEASE.jar:5.1.12.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.sandeepan.entity.Person
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:3045) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2796) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2782) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1230) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3499) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.14.Final.jar:5.3.14.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You need an EntityScan annotation, or better, to respect the conventional layout, and put the application class in the com.example.sandeepan package instead of com.example.sandeepan.demo.

Comment: Wow that worked. Very difficult to figure out from the error for me!