# Error "Unable to locate persister: ...." when saving entity to H2 database with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, h2

I am trying to create an in-memory database using H2 as the database and Hibernate as the ORM.

Versions:

- Java: 17
- Hibernate: 6.4.0.Final
- H2: 2.2.224
- JPA: 2.2

I have the following entry point for the app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory()) {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setName("John Doe");
            newUser.setEmail("john.doe@example.com");
            
            try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
                Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                session.persist(newUser);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

(collected into single function for clarity)

This is my user POJO:

```
package Application.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And lastly, this is my Hibernate configuration file named 'hibernate.cfg.xml':

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
        <mapping class="Application.Model.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Executing the above code gives me the error:
"Unable to locate persister: AtmEngine.Model.User"

I tried following other solutions to the problem I found here:
[Getting hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister on application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438059/getting-hibernate-unknownentitytypeexception-unable-to-locate-persister-on-appl)

https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/16n25jx/orghibernateunknownentitytypeexception_unable_to/

But they did not solve the issue.

I also tried removing the @GeneratedValue annotation, but that did not work either.

The session factory gets built without errors and the session is also opened without errors.

Are any you able to spot the issue? Thanks!